# How to organize junit test suites using Allure

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, junit, allure

So far, beside Junit and Jenkins, I used log4j to textual reporting results of test cases but now I want to use Allure, for generating clearer and more transparent reports from my selenium tests. 
I'm using maven project where single test case is a java class, and consists of steps which every of them is also a java class. it looks like this:

```
public class FirstTestCase() {
    new Step1(driver).run();
    new Step2(driver).run();
    new Step3(driver).run();
}

public class SecondTestCase() {
    … second test case steps ...
}
```

In every step - „run” - contains selenium code.

Individual test cases are grouped into larger sets. For example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    FirstTestCase.class,
    SecondTestCase.class
})
public class SetOfTests {}
```

Finally, I have one major class (which is called “TestRunner”) in which the respective sets are activated. It looks like this:

```
public class TestRunner {
    @Test
    public void main() {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(
        SetOfTests.class
    );
```

So, class hierarchy in my project looks like:

```
TestRunner |-
    SetOfTests |-
        FirstTestCase |-
                        |- Step 1
                        |- Step 2
                        |- ....
        SecondTestCase |-
                        |- Step 1
                        |-Step 2
                        |- ....
```

Now, my question is:
How will be best approach to add Allure annotations (like a @Stories,@Features, @Steps... ) that 
after the Jenkins “build”, when report will be generated, result will be presented in form as a hierarchy above

Note that, jenkins is configured, works and also generates a report but not in such a form as I want.

Just I need to know in simple way in which test and which step the error occurred

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Allure XSD file](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-model/src/main/resources/allure.xsd) you will see that currently (1.4.x series) we support the following structure:

```
TestSuite|
         TestCase|
                  Step|
                      Substep|
                             ...
```

So test suite can contain a set of test cases (nested test cases are not supported) and each test case can contain a hierarchy of steps with unlimited depth. I would implement a custom JUnit adapter for your case - this is as simple as creating one Java class like the [following](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-junit-adaptor/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/junit/AllureRunListener.java) which implements JUnit [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) interface.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll look at this in the near future